# What are Text Filters and Input Formats?

Tags: 7, views, entities, input-formats

In views, when I add a field of type body, there are some options given: text_default, text_plain, text_trimmed.

How do these options filter the contents of the field and where can they be found in the code??

Answer (score 0):

These are called 'text filters', and a text filter is made up of 'input formats'. Input formats are defined in [hook_filter_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7.x).

You can read more about text filters here: https://www.drupal.org/node/213156